# How to read application insights output

Tags: azure-application-insights

We just integrated appInsights to our app, as great as it is, we are bit confused on the output.

For example, from failures, it shows that we have over 200 failures in one api.
This is not a problem, but why it counts only 16 ComException? I assume we will have at least 219 exceptions (as 219 500), so does it mean appInsight can't work out what are the exceptions?

Then look at top 3 dependency failures, it count 1.53k. Is it azure including some internal retry logic happened in Azure Table nuget package we used? but if this zure table failed 1.53k times, then there must be at least 1.53k exceptions?

How we should read this table?

[image]

Comment: The numbers are quite low, so it doesn't look that sampling should be involved (though please double check). Even with sampling the numbers should align assuming correlation is not broken (Application Insights sample either in or out the whole request with all outgoing requests/exceptions).

Comment: Can you please drill into these 500s/COMException? You should see end-to-end transaction details and if correlation works then you should see both appearing in the same chart. Please paste a representative screenshot.

Comment: As mentioned, click into the counts - view the transaction details and you'll see where things are happening. A failure is just something that returned 'false' in dependency telemetry, which for some components might be normal operation. i.e. perhaps there are some 409 conflicts in your dependency failures that are reported as such, but actually your app continued OK and this didn't cause any adverse impact. Tuning the telemetry to only give you the things you're really interested in is an important part of App Insights.